# How can I increase the mouse pointer speed beyond the limits set by system in 17.10

Tags: mouse, 17.10, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 on Asus X200MA laptop.

Also tried
"xset m acceleration threshold"
It is effective in reducing pointer speed but not much in increasing that.

My touchpad ID 14, device ID 267
"xinput set-prop 14 267 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000" doesn't work for me.
It says,
"X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x10b
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20"

I also tried:
"xinput --set-prop 14 267 0.1"
It gives same response.

Any other suggestion?